# Identifying combinations removing 2 possiblities from a set

Tags: probability

```
If I have a set A,B,C,D,E,F,G
```

I am looking for a recipe to identify all possible combinations of letters removing all combinations of 2 letters.

In this case the result would be

```
CDEFG remove AB
ABEFG remove CD
ABCDG remove EF
BDEFG remove AC
ACEFG remove BD

etc..
```

I want to know all the removal possibilities

Comment: What are you looking for?  Is it different from just $\binom 75$?

Comment: Im not a math person. My question my be simple or complex I am uncertain

Comment: The problem is that your question is unclear.  $\binom 75=\binom 72=21$ represents the number of ways to choose $5$ (or equivalently $2$) elements out of a possible $7$.  In general we have $\binom nk =\frac {n!}{k!(n-k)!}$.  However, I am not at all sure that this is the answer you are looking for.

Comment: @lulu if I want to identify all the possible "removes" like remove AB, remove CD etc. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You want a list instead of a count?  Ok.  Then let's suppose that the first deleted number is less than the second (meaning that it comes up earlier in your list).  There are then $6$ choices for the first one.  Given that you first remove entry $i$, there are $7-i$ candidates for the second.  This provides a count and an algorithm for listing them.

Comment: @lulu I am not looking for a count, rather the output would be all the possible "removes" AB,CD, EF, AC, BD, etc in no order. Also AB and BA are the samething

Comment: I understand you want more than a count, that's why I gave an algorithm for listing them.  By choosing the "lesser" letter first, I avoid the symmetry problem.  That is, my algorithm does yield $AB$ as $A<B$ but it never yields $BA$.

Comment: To illustrate my algorithm:  if you start with the least number $A$, there are $6$ candidates for the other.  Thus $AB,AC,AD,AE,AF,AG$.  If you start with $B$ there are $5$ candidates for the other, so $BC,BD,BE,BF,BG$.  And so on.  If you start with $F$ there is only the once possibility, $FG$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of ways to choose the two that you remove is the number of ways to choose $2$ objects from a set of $7$. This is known as a [combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination), and is written and calculated as follows:

$$\binom{7}{2} = \frac{7!}{(7-2)!\,2!} =-\frac{7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1}{\left(5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1\right)\left(2 \cdot 1\right)} = \boxed{21}$$

The exclamation marks here stand for [factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial).

---

Instead of choosing the two that you remove, you could also choose the $5$ that you don't remove. This would be $$\binom{7}{5}$$ which evaluates to the same number. In general, $$\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n}{n-k}$$

---

A list of all $21$ possibilities for the two letters removed: $$\mathrm{AB, AC, AD, AE, AF, AG, BC, BD, BE, BF, BG,} $$
$$ \mathrm{CD, CE, CF, CG, DE, DF, DG, EF, EG, FG}$$

Comment: I am looking to display all the removal possibilities instead of the result from removing

Comment: There are $21$ removal possibilities. You could write them all out systematically ... are you looking for a computer program to do that for you? If so, you could ask on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/), I think ...

Comment: @nlstack01 I've edited my answer to include a list of all $21$ possibilities

Comment: how did you list all of the combinations? By hand?

Answer (score 0):

Number of combinations =$5!\times^7C_5$

Answer (score 0):

So you want, not just the number of such possibilities but the actual lists themselves?  The simplest way to do that is to list all combinations in a specific order.  Taking "A" as the first letter they are "AB", "AC", "AD", "AE", and "AF".  Now B- "BC", "BD", "BE", "BF" (we do not count "BA" since that was already given as "AB".  We list each letter with all **succeeding** letters.).
"CD", "CE", "CF".  "DE", "DF".  "EF".  Now it is easy to list the 5 letters left after we remove those.  Notice that there are a total of 6+ 5+ 4+ 3+ 2+ 1= 21 as others said.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are looking for an algorithm? It seems that your problem is equivalent to finding all the pairs of letters in the set. The below algorithm will generate the pairs you are looking for where $S$ is a set of $n$ letters. The following Python code will generate the pairs you are looking for.

(I tried to write it in pseudocode, but I am not familiar with mechanisms on StackExchange to do that nicely).

```
def findPairs(S): #given a set S, return all the pairs
    pairs = []
    for i in range(0,len(S)-1): #for each letter
        for j in range(i+1,len(S)): #for each letter past the first one we chose
            pairs.append(S[i]+S[j]) #add the pair of letters, '+' is string concatenation
    return pairs
```

Notice that in this algorithm, we avoid duplicates like $AB$ and $BA$ by only picking pairs where the index of the first letter is less than the index of the second.